# How to append xml tags using Java stream

Tags: java

```
map1   {1234=false, 456=false, 789=false, 876=false}
```

I have a map with key and values and printing above. I need to append with `<emp>` tag for these empids,
but when I use stream API the final result is wierd.

```
String l= map1.entrySet().stream()
.map( n -> b.append("<emp>"+n.getKey()+"</emp" )).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

```
<emp>1234</emp>
<emp>1234</emp>
<emp>456</emp>
<emp>1234</emp>
<emp>456</emp>
<emp>789</emp>
<emp>1234</emp>
<emp>456</emp>
<emp>789</emp>
<emp>876</emp>
```

Comment: What is the `b` that you append the values to?

Comment: StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder ();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
Map<Integer, Boolean> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put(1234, false);
map.put(456, false);
map.put(789, false);
map.put(876, false);

String str = map.keySet().stream()
                .map(key -> "<emp>" + key + "</emp>")
                .collect(Collectors.joining());

System.out.println(str);    // <emp>1234</emp><emp>456</emp><emp>789</emp><emp>876</emp>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix the output you need to remove the StringBuilder `b` i.e.

```
String l = map1.entrySet().stream()
    .map( n -> "<emp>"+n.getKey()+"</emp>").collect(Collectors.joining());
```

In your code `b` is keeping the values of the previous iterations since you append the values to it which results in the repeated elements.

Alternatively you could also append every value to the StringBuilder using a stream with foreach i.e.

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
map1.entrySet().stream().forEach(n -> b.append("<emp>" + n.getKey() + "</emp>"));
System.out.println(b);
```